# How do I write the type of an iterator passed to a function?

Tags: loops, parsing, vector, iterator, rust

I am trying to write a parser that passes an iterator over a vector to a function. The code is similar to this:

```
fn foo(itr : ???) {
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        if *c != 0 {
            break;
        }
        println!("{}", *c);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0; 10];
    let itr = v.iter();
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        foo(itr);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to write the type of the iterator over the vector. I tried putting the wrong type `u32` to see what type `rustc` expected: `core::slice::Iter<'_, _>`. When I try to use `core::slice` rustc complains `Use of undeclared type or module 'core::slice'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many types of iterators; most of the time, what you really want is a function that is able to consume any of them. To do this, the idiomatic solution is to use generics.

```
fn foo<'a, T: Iterator<Item=&'a i32>>(mut itr: T) {
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        if *c != 0 {
            break;
        }
        println!("{}", *c);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0; 10];
    let mut itr = v.iter();
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        foo(itr);
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't compile though, since it moves `itr` into `foo`, then tries to use it again on the `while let`. To solve this, we need to pass the iterator by reference instead.

```
fn foo<'a, T: Iterator<Item=&'a i32>>(itr: &mut T) {
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        if *c != 0 {
            break;
        }
        println!("{}", *c);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0; 10];
    let mut itr = v.iter();
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        foo(&mut itr);
    }
}
```

Instead of generics, we can also use a trait object:

```
fn foo<'a>(itr: &mut Iterator<Item=&'a i32>) {
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        if *c != 0 {
            break;
        }
        println!("{}", *c);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0; 10];
    let mut itr = v.iter();
    while let Some(c) = itr.next() {
        foo(&mut itr);
    }
}
```

The chapter on [trait objects](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html) from the Rust book explains the difference between these solutions.

Comment: Awesome! FYI if you have mutually recursive functions like in a recursive descent parser, rust will not be compile if you use generics, but if you use a trait object it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add

```
use std::slice::Iter;
```

and the type was

```
fun foo<'a>(itr : &mut Iter<'a, i32>) {}
```

Comment: Note that this would only allow your function to be used with iterators returned by the `iter()` method on slices, but not with, say, `iter().map(|x| ...))` because it has another type. You need to use generics here, as @FrancisGagné suggests.